# curl_setopt only returning some of the response

Tags: php, curl

I am sending a request to our server and when it returns, it only has about 25% of the information that I get when I paste the same URL into my web browser.  The data in the full version is about 4500 lines at 550KB.  Here is the script :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $q);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo "The return is : " . $return;
```

How can I all of the data?

Comment: does any of that output contain html metacharacters? Your browser will be trying to RENDER that "html", and if it's not valid html, will munge the rendering. do a "view source" to confirm that you really are missing stuff. Remember that browser's jobs are to LIE to you. they don't show you html, they show you what they THINK the html should look like.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  It was receiving an XML, and after inspecting it I was able to see all the nodes.  The biggest problem was it was passing in the cookies when I hit it from my browser and wasn't when using the PHP.